# How to integrate multiple Luis model to bot framework

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a bot which will respond to users query to my private use cases. Similarly i would like to enable bot to answer some of common questions like Weather or directions etc. So i built a own app in [Luis](https://www.luis.ai) and also trying to use Pre-built cortana intents. Sample below

```
[LuisModel("c413b2ef-382c-45bd-8ff0-f76dad0e2a821", "697asfc173ce6f40aca4c99e7d38assad6cad")]
public class myClass: LuisDialog<T>
{
}
```

This will only accept either Cortana Intents or my own Intents depends on subscription id and key.

How can i use both the Luis models in my Class? Please help

Answer (score 2):

Around 20 days ago, they updated the LuisDialog to support multiple LuisModel and ILuisService instances (check this [commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/commit/87177cfc64fe9b2c7841940dd901959c36a4245e)). The change was already released in NuGet 1.2.4.

Comment: still am confused how to add multiple dialogs. As you can see my code i annotate my class with Luis model. Tried given another one model, but it is not detecting.

Comment: @Satheesh probably you are using the old version of the framework? It works for me if I decorate the class with multiple models. Huge thanks to ejadib for this info!

Comment: @K48 Yes it works for me too. If we put multiple models directly there are  more chances of picking None Intent in second model. We have to do a tweak to make it work. But i tried a little different. I placed my Intents in different classes and uses multiple LUIS models. It was not detecting. But now am glad to say, i achieved that.

Answer (score 0):

My Bot will answer different usecases. So i have to use multiple classes for all each usecase. Use of this code is, we can write our task(anotated with Intents) in multiples classes.

I found solution by overriding the Handler Method of `LuisDialog` as below. My `Baseform` inherits the `LuisDialog` class. All other classes which have intents will inherit my `BaseForm`

```
protected override IDictionary<string, IntentActivityHandler> GetHandlersByIntent()
        {
            var classCollection = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                        .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetTypes())
                        .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseForm)));
            List<KeyValuePair<string, IntentActivityHandler>> handler = new List<KeyValuePair<string, IntentActivityHandler>>();
            foreach (var item in classCollection)
            {
                handler.AddRange(MyLuisDialog.EnumerateHandlers(Activator.CreateInstance(item)).ToList());
            }            
            return handler.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
        }
```

in the code there is `EnumerateHandlers`method which is just a copy of the same from Luis Dialog sdk.